# simulation of vanet project with omnet++ and sumo,

Tags: python, simulation, omnet++, sumo, ns-3

I need to simulate my vanet project that's coded with python. I want to use ns-3 or omnet++, and SUMO.

please help me, I don't know how to link my vanet project with the simulator (ns-3 or OMNET++).

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a good playlist where you could start from: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLaBPUIXZ8s4AwAk5EelikvvyG4EzX2hpx

Answer (score 0):

Options here include pybind11. Check stackoverflow q and a on linking pybind11 and OMNET++.

Other option is using omnetpy. Check for GitHub project on omnetpy.

In both cases you need to learn OMNET++ first.